# Random Red Flashing Pixels on Macbook pro 2012 (WINDOWS 10 BOOTCAMP)

Tags: display

I have a problem with my MacBook pro 2012. I used boot camp to install windows 10. When I load windows 10 up, it has randomly red flashing pixels. When I play games like Roblox, the pixels flash more aggressively (more pixels).

Comment: Did you install the Boot Camp support software? Also, sometimes you have to install NVidia/AMD drivers directly from the chipset manufacturer's site.

Comment: How do I find what chipset is used in my MacBook pro 

MacBook Pro 2012 Details,
Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5,
Memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3,
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB,

Comment: "Intel HD Graphics 4000" right there in your comment. Abandoned by Microsoft for Windows 10, there are only rudimentary drivers available - try https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28799/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-33-?product=81499

Comment: It still has random red flashing dots when I go into a game (Roblox).